# DrawLine() and Cursor.Position not showing same coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows form application. When I press Draw button in it, it draws a line:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        projectilePathPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        projectilePathGraphics.DrawLine(projectilePathPen, 150, 150, 450, 150);
}
```

I have a Mouse Move event for the form (to get current mouse's coordinates):

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        { 

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

        int actualX, actualY;

        actualX = Cursor.Position.X - 150;
        actualY = 150 - Cursor.Position.Y;

        labelX.Text = "Actual X: " +actualX.ToString();
        labelY.Text = "Actual Y: " + actualY.ToString();
    }
```

Whenerever I place this cursor, its giving me wrong values. I have placed it on the start of the line just drew and it's not giving (0,0) as predictably as it should be.

Comment: Cursor Position is probably relative to the screen, have you tried using the `MouseEventArgs`?

Comment: No. How should I use it?

Comment: [MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), either `e.Location` or `e.X` sounds like it might do what you are wanting to do

Comment: Also Look into  PointToClient and PointToScreen

Comment: @Sayse Thank You! It works. I would love to know the individual who down-voted this question and would like to know the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
actualX = Cursor.Position.X - 150;
actualY = 150 - Cursor.Position.Y;
```

with these:

```
actualX = e.X - 150;
actualY = 150 - e.Y;
```

`e.X` and `e.Y` give you the local position of the cursor relative to your `panel1` while `Cursor.Postion` is the global position of the cursor on the screen.

Comment: It's correct answer but @Sayse already answered it in comment.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan upvote and accept it then. Site policy is that answers should not be posted in comments anyway.